# Removing all instances of an element from a custom LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, element

Im trying to remove all people from the list who have the same course name in my custom LinkedList class. I have managed to get my programme to delete people individually based on number however can not figure out how to remove multiple at once. I have browsed online for any solutions and have tried multiple so far but none to any success I also attempted one myself but also no success any help or links to were I could learn mode would be greatly appreciated. Below is my Driver, LinkedList, and LinearNode class. I have also removed code I beleive is not relevant to this solution :).

**Linked List Class**

```
public class LinkedList<T> implements LinkedListADT<T> {
    
     private int count;  // the current number of elements in the list
     private LinearNode<T> list; //pointer to the first element 
     private LinearNode<T> last; //pointer to the last element 
     
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------
     //  Creates an empty list.
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        public LinkedList()
        {
           this.count = 0;
           this.last = null;
           this.list = null;
        }
       public void add (T element)
       {      
           LinearNode<T> node = new LinearNode<T> (element); 
       
           if (size() == 0) {  
                this.last = node; // This is the last and the 
                this.list = node; // first node
                this.count++;
           }//end if
           else
             { 
                  last.setNext(node); // add node to the end of the list
                  last = node; // now make this the new last node.
                  this.count++;   
              } //end else
       }
       
       public T remove()
       {
           LinearNode<T> current = list;
           LinearNode<T> temp = list;
           T result = null;
          
            if (current == null) {
                System.out.println("There are no such employees in the list");
            }//end if
            else {
            
                result = this.list.getElement();
                temp = list;
                this.list = this.list.getNext();
                temp.setNext(null); //dereference the original first element
                count--;
            }//end else
            return result;

       }
       
       public T remove(T element) 
       {
           LinearNode<T> current = list;
           LinearNode<T> previous = list;
           LinearNode<T> temp;
           T result = null;
           
            if (current == null) {
                
                System.out.println("There are no such employees in the list");
            }//end if
            else {
                
                for (current = this.list; current != null && !current.getElement().equals(element); current = current.getNext())
                   {
                    previous = current;
                
                   }
                if(current == null) {
                    System.out.println("No such employee on the list");
                }
                else if (current == list)
                {
                    remove();
                }
                else if(current == last) {
                    previous.setNext(null); 
                    this.last = previous.getNext();
                    
                    count--;
                }
                else
                {
                    previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                    count--;
                }
                
            }
            
            return result;
       }
**
  My attempted Solution**
       
       public T clear(T element) {
           T result = null;
            while (this.list != null && this.list.getElement() == element) {
                this.list = this.list.getNext();
             count--;
            }

            if (this.list == null) {
                return result;
            }

            LinearNode<T> current = this.list;
            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                if (current.getNext().getElement() == element) {
                    current.setNext(current.getNext());
                    count--;
                } else {
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
                
            }
            return result;
        }
      
}
```

**LinearNode Class**

```
public class LinearNode<T>
{
   private LinearNode<T> next;
   private T element;

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates an empty node.
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   public LinearNode()
   {
      this.next = null;
      this.element = null;
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates a node storing the specified element.
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   public LinearNode (T elem)
   {
      this.next = null;
      this.element = elem;
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the node that follows this one.
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   public LinearNode<T> getNext()
   {
      return this.next;
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets the node that follows this one.
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   public void setNext (LinearNode<T> node)
   {
      this.next = node;
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns the element stored in this node.
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   public T getElement()
   {
      return this.element;
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets the element stored in this node.
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   public void setElement (T elem)
   {
      this.element = elem;
   }
}
```

**Driver Class**

```
public class TrainingCourses {

    LinkedList<employee>list;
    int Size =10;
     int numberofEmployees=0;
    
    
    
    public TrainingCourses() {
     list = new LinkedList<employee>();
    
    

     inputEmployee();
     displayEmployee();
     deleteCourses();
     displayEmployee();

         
          
    }
    

    
    public void inputEmployee() {
        employee a;
        a = null;
        String number,name,courseName = null;
        int years;
        
        
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
    
         for (int count = 1; count<=numberofEmployees; count++){
        System.out.println("Input employee number");
        number = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input employee name");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input years at organisation");
        years = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
        if(years >=5) {
        System.out.println("Input course name");
        courseName = scan.nextLine();
        }else {
            System.out.println("Can not join training course employee must be with organisation 5 or more years");
        
        }
        
        a = new employee(number,name,years,courseName);
        
        
        list.add(a);
    
            }
    
    }
    public void displayEmployee() {
         System.out.println("\nDisplaying all employees....");

            System.out.println(list.toString());
        
    }
    
    

        
    public void deleteCourses(){
         {
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                employee b = null;
                String number,name,courseName;
                int years;

                System.out.println("Enter employee number you wish to remove");
                number = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Input employee name");
                name = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Input years at organisation");
                years = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Input course name");
                courseName = scan.nextLine();
                
                b = new employee(number,name,years,courseName);
                  
                list.clear(b);
               
        }
            
        
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new TrainingCourses();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you want, because of you wrote you want *"to remove all people from the list who have the same course name"*, but your code never checks only property, your code checks equality everywhere.

This example clear function removes all elements equals to param and returns count of removed elements.

```
public long clear(T element) {
    long result = 0L;
    
    LinearNode<T> current = this.list;
    LinearNode<T> previous = null;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getElement().equals(element)) {
            if (previous != null) {
                if (current.getNext() != null) {
                    previous.setNext(current.getNext());
                } else {
                    this.last = previous;
                }
            } else if (current.getNext() != null) {
                this.list = current.getNext();
            } else {
                this.list = this.last = null;
            }
            this.count--;
            result++;
        } else {
            previous = current;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    return result;
}
```

And after all `.equals(..)` only true, if the compared Objects has an equals() method and checks its content equality, otherwise two Objects equals by `==` operator, if they are exactly the same (not by there's contents).

Comment: Ah I see thanks for pointing that out will thank you for the assistance shall give this a try